# Как сделать ALTER TABLE для slave для postgres 9.5 pglogical?

Tags: postgresql

Есть логическая реплика в PG 9.5 pglogical, но не очень понятно как делать там `alter`, все остальные изменения работают, примерно так:

```
SELECT pglogical.replicate_ddl_command('update public.stats SET value=94 where id=6247');  
replicate_ddl_command ----------------------- t (1 row)
```

но

```
SELECT pglogical.replicate_ddl_command('ALTER TABLE public.stats ADD Phone CHARACTER VARYING(20)');  
replicate_ddl_command ----------------------- t (1 row)
```

на `slave` не меняется, столбика не добавляется, а после этого `update` сразу вгоняет реплику в `down`

Как быть? Есть варианты делать `alter`?

Comment: Сам спросил, сам отвечаю :) Команда, передающая alter, вот

SELECT pglogical.replicate_ddl_command(command :='ALTER TABLE public.stats ADD Phone CHARACTER VARYING(20)',replication_sets:=ARRAY['insert_update']);

удалить столбик phone
SELECT pglogical.replicate_ddl_command(command :='ALTER TABLE public.stats DROP Phone',replication_sets:=ARRAY['insert_update']);